# Crear archivo zip a partir de archivos en servidor ftp

Tags: php, ftp, zip

Con el framework codeigniter necesito crear un archivo zip a partir de archivos que están en un servidor ftp, esta es la función que estoy utilizando para eso:

```
public function generate_zip(){

$this->load->library('ftp');
$this->load->library('zip');
$this->load->helper('download');

global $arrayFtp;

//Obtener archivos dentro del rango de fechas
$docus = $this->documentModel->git_documents_by_range($this->input->post('dateFrom'), $this->input->post('dateTo'));

$this->ftp->connect($credentials);

$pathRemote = REMOTEPATH.'/documents/';

foreach($docus as $val):

$path = $pathRemote.'docu_'.$val->code.'.pdf';

//Aquí es donde trato de sacar el contenido del archivo
$handle = file_get_contents($path);

$this->zip->add_data('docu_'.$val->code.'.pdf', $handle);
endforeach;

$name = 'mydata1.txt';
$data = 'A Data String!';

$this->zip->add_data($name, $data);
//$this->zip->archive(APPPATH.'/ftp/myzip.zip');
$this->zip->download('myzip.zip');

$this->ftp->close();
}
```

El archivo que puse a modo hardcode mydata1.txt y su contenido si se guardan bien en el ftp, pero los archivos dentro del loop no se guardan bien. Alguna idea??

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera se crean los fichero php:

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./test112.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)===TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile("test.txt");
    $zip->addFile("test2.txt");
    $zip->close();
    echo "Fichero creado con exito"
}
else{
    echo "Fichero no creado"
}
?>
```

Para más información mira la [Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/zip.examples.php)

Comment: Gracias pero realmente busco como obtener el contenido de un archivo que esta en un servidor por medio de ftp.